# How to get dependency tree/graph in NestJS?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

Nestjs provides out of the box DI container very conveniently but as project gets more complex it is easy to lose the full picture of all dependencies and their order.

**Question**: Is there a way to get a list of all dependencies (modules, providers, controllers...) possibly in a way that can be put into a tree/graph? I'm sure Nestjs tracks this information internally and I'm wondering what would be the best way to access it.

(I found [`nestjs-dependency-graph`] but it scans the modules manually for metadata, doesn't find all dependencies and tends to go into infinite loop)

Comment: I'm working on something for this, but currently [compodoc](https://compodoc.app/guides/usage.html) is going to be your best bet which will generate a full document of your server.

Answer (score 17):

I've tried [nestjs-spelunker](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-spelunker) like mentioned in @Jay's comment and it's really solid.

You just need to generate the graph text and paste it in the [mermaid-live-editor](https://mermaid.live/)

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SpelunkerModule } from 'nestjs-spelunker';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule);

  // 1. Generate the tree as text
  const tree = SpelunkerModule.explore(app);
  const root = SpelunkerModule.graph(tree);
  const edges = SpelunkerModule.findGraphEdges(root);
  const mermaidEdges = edges
    .filter( // I'm just filtering some extra Modules out
      ({ from, to }) =>
        !(
          from.module.name === 'ConfigHostModule' ||
          from.module.name === 'LoggerModule' ||
          to.module.name === 'ConfigHostModule' ||
          to.module.name === 'LoggerModule'
        ),
    )
    .map(({ from, to }) => `${from.module.name}-->${to.module.name}`);
  console.log(`graph TD\n\t${mermaidEdges.join('\n\t')}`);
  
  // 2. Copy and paste the log content in "https://mermaid.live/"
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using madge npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge

Simply as `npx madge dist/main.js --image graph.png`

Will generate such graph

[image: graph]